How to add values to apigee evaluation instance?
Created a new empty KVM in Apigee (evaluation version) but we could not able to add any values to it.
It has only delete option no edit option. How to add values to the KVM named "sample-kvm"?
Screenshot of KVM panel

Please go through the documentation - https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/cache/key-value-maps#create

We cannot directly add or retrieve data from the KVM entries via the Apigee console. We need to use the Apigee Management API to add data (i.e. key value pairs) to the KVM entry and If you need to retrieve or update data during the proxy runtime, utilize the KeyValueMapOperations policy.
